# How to add Attribute Mappings From json like this using RestKit?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, restkit

I am using below to add Attribute Mappings

```
RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Timeline" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"title": @"title"}];
```

But how to add attachments.title mappings? attachments is an array of dictionarys. I want to access the title in attachments.

```
[
    {
        "category": @"tech",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "title": "Mac Home",
                "media": [
                    {
                        "sizes": {
                            "small": [
                                48,
                                48
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "image"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "Group",
            }
        ],
        "title": "Joined Group",
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't map the array contents directly into the same object, there is no way to deal with the multiplicity. You need to add a new entity to your model and a relationship and then configure a mapping for that entity and a relationship configuration between the 2 mappings.